# QTabWidget setCornerWidget with expanding width

Tags: qt, tabs, qsizepolicy

I simply want the cornerWidget of a QTabWidget to expand its width as mush as possible. I have tried setting the QSizePolicy to {Expanding, Expanding} but I can't get it to work. I want to have some tabs to the left and a widget occupying all left over space to the right.

I can get it to occupy a fix width by overriding the sizeHint, but that's not dynamically resizing. Anyone know how to do this? Is it a bug in Qt?

I'm using Qt 5.0.2 in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

QTabBar expanding is set by default. So probably you will need to unset it:

```
tabWidget->tabBar()->setExpanding(false);
```

[QTabBar * QTabWidget::tabBar() const](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qtabwidget.html#tabBar)

[QTabBar expanding](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qtabbar.html#expanding-prop)